# Fittslaw implementation Pygame is spawning alot of circles instead of only just one

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to do a fittslaw implementation using pygame but when clicking the dot in the middle it spawn alot of dots randomly until it stops and spawns only one for some reason.

Ik there is smth wrong with the loop i just cant figure out a solution.

My humble and very scuffed code:

```
import pygame
import math  
import random


pygame.init()

width = 1024
height = 768
display = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))


black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
purple = (128, 0, 128)
grey = (128, 128, 128)
sky = (0, 0, 220)
blue = (85, 206, 255)
orange = (255, 127, 80)
red = (200, 0, 0)
light_red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 200, 0)
light_green = (0, 255, 0)
colors = [white, grey, purple, sky, blue, orange, red, light_red, green, light_green]

clock = pygame.time.Clock() 

cx = random.randint(20, width - 20)
cy = random.randint(20, height - 20)
width_of_circle = random.randint(14, 20)
pygame.draw.circle(display, green, (512, 384), width_of_circle)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    #pygame.draw.circle(display, green, (512, 384), width_of_circle)
    x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
    y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    sqx1 = (x - 512)**2
    sqy2 = (y - 384)**2
    sqx = (x - cx)**2
    sqy = (y - cy)**2

    if math.sqrt(sqx + sqy) < width_of_circle and click[0] == 1:
            display.fill(black) 
        #cx = random.randint(20, width - 20)
        #cy = random.randint(20, height - 20)
            width_of_circle = random.randint(14, 20)
            pygame.draw.circle(display, green, (512, 384), width_of_circle)
        
    elif math.sqrt(sqx1 + sqy2) < width_of_circle and click[0] == 1:
            display.fill(black)
            cx = random.randint(20, width - 20)
            cy = random.randint(20, height - 20)
            width_of_circle = random.randint(14, 20)
            pygame.draw.circle(display, random.choice(colors), (cx, cy), width_of_circle)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick()
```

I tried moving the random var outside the loop but that didnt work

Answer (score 1):

While `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` returns the current state of the buttons, the  `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` and `MOUSEBUTTONUP` occurs only once a button is pressed. So you have to redraw the scene in every frame and you have to use the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event instead of `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`:

```py
import pygame, math, random

pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
clock = pygame.time.Clock() 

cx, cy = display.get_rect().center
width_of_circle = 20
circle_color = "green"

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            x, y = event.pos
            dx = x - cx
            dy = y - cy
            if math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) < width_of_circle:
                cx = random.randint(20, display.get_width() - 20)
                cy = random.randint(20, display.get_height() - 20)
                width_of_circle = random.randint(14, 20)
                circle_color = pygame.Color(0)
                circle_color.hsla = (random.randrange(360), 100, 50, 100)

    display.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.circle(display, circle_color, (cx, cy), width_of_circle)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(100)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)